# Can't access the Velocity ProjectManager in an admin configuration form for a JIRA plugin

Tags: velocity, jira-plugin

I build an admin configuration form for an existing JIRA plugin based on Atlassian's own [admin configuration form tutorial](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Creating+an+Admin+Configuration+Form).
By now the template appears when clicking the configure button, except one problem: I can't access the Velocity ProjectManager class. When explicitly testing it by simply writing `$projectManager` into the Velocity template, the string itself appears on the website instead of being resolved as a variable. How can I resolve it as a variable?
Here are some shortened versions of the code files 'admin.vm' and 'atlassian-plugin.xml':

admin.vm

```
<html>
<head>
<title>$i18n.getText("com.example.jira.PluginConfiguration.head")</title>
<meta content="admin_plugins_menu/upm_section" name="admin.active.section">
<meta content="upm-admin-link" name="admin.active.tab">
<meta name="decorator" content="atl.admin">
<meta name="application-base-url" content="$applicationProperties.getBaseUrl()">
$webResourceManager.requireResource("com.example.jira:resources")
</head>
<body id="jira" class="page-type-admin ">
    <form name="PluginConfigurationForm" action="/secure/PluginConfiguration.jspa" method="post" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <input type="hidden" name="atl_token" value="${atl_token}" class="aui">
            <div>
                <h2 class="aui top-label">$i18n.getText('com.example.jira.PluginConfiguration.title')</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden">
                <input name="id" type="hidden" value="${action.id}"> <input
                    name="returnUrl" type="hidden" value="$!{action.returnUrl}">
            </div>
            $projectManager
            <div class="buttons-container form-footer">
                <div class="buttons">
                    <input accesskey="s" class="button" id="PluginConfiguration-submit"
                        name="PluginConfiguration" title="Press Ctrl+Alt+s to submit this form"
                        type="submit" value="$i18n.getText('com.example.jira.PluginConfiguration.input.button.save')">
                    <a accesskey="`" class="cancel" href="/plugins/servlet/upm"
                        id="PluginConfiguration-cancel" title="Press Ctrl+Alt+` to cancel">$i18n.getText('com.example.jira.PluginConfiguration.input.button.cancel')</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

atlassian-plugin.xml

```
<atlassian-plugin key="${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}"
name="${project.artifactId}" plugins-version="2">
<plugin-info>
    <description>${project.description}</description>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}" />
    <param name="plugin-icon">img/Project_Logo.png</param>
    <param name="plugin-logo">img/Project_Logo.png</param>
    <param name="configure.url"><![CDATA[/plugins/servlet/ConfigurePlugin/admin]]></param>
</plugin-info>

<resource type="i18n" name="i18n_PluginConfiguration" location="com.example.jira/PluginConfiguration" />

<component-import key="pluginScheduler">
    <description>SAL Scheduler</description>
    <interface>com.atlassian.sal.api.scheduling.PluginScheduler
    </interface>
</component-import>

<component-import key="pluginSettingsFactory"
    interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.pluginsettings.PluginSettingsFactory" />

<component-import key="transactionTemplate"
    interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.transaction.TransactionTemplate" />

<component-import key="userManager"
    interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.user.UserManager" />

<component-import key="loginUriProvider"
    interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.auth.LoginUriProvider" />

<component-import key="renderer"
    interface="com.atlassian.templaterenderer.velocity.one.six.VelocityTemplateRenderer" />

<component-import key="applicationProperties"
    interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties" />


<servlet key="admin-servlet"
    class="${project.groupId}.PluginConfigurationServlet">
    <url-pattern>/ConfigurePlugin/admin</url-pattern>
</servlet>


<rest key="rest"
    path="/project-admin"
    version="1.0">
    <description>Provides REST resources for the admin UI.</description>
</rest>


<template-context-item key="applicationPropertiesContextItem"
    component-ref="applicationProperties" context-key="applicationProperties"
    name="Application Properties Context Item" />


<web-section key="ProjectAdminMenu" name="Project Admin Section"
    location="admin_plugins_menu" weight="10">
    <label>Project</label>
    <description key="Project Administration Section"></description>
</web-section>

<web-item key="PluginConfiguration-web-item" name="Plugin Configuration Web Item"
    i18n-name-key="com.example.jira.PluginConfiguration-web-item.name"
    section="admin_plugins_menu/ProjectAdminMenu" weight="46">
    <description i18n-name-key="PluginConfiguration-web-item.description"></description>
    <label key="com.example.jira.PluginConfiguration-web-item.label" />
    <link linkId="PluginConfiguration-web-item-link">/plugins/servlet/ConfigurePlugin/admin?decorator=admin/</link>
    <tooltip>Configure the Project Jira Plugin</tooltip>
</web-item>


<web-resource name="PluginConfiguration Web Resource"
    i18n-name-key="com.example.jira.PluginConfiguration-web-resource.name"
    key="PluginConfiguration-web-resource">
    <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
    <description i18n-name-key="PluginConfiguration-web-resource.description"></description>
    <context>jira.admin</context>
    <transformation extension="js">
        <transformer key="jsI18n" />
    </transformation>
    <resource type="download" name="PluginConfiguration.js"
        location="javascript/PluginConfiguration.js">
        <property key="content-type" value="text/javascript" />
    </resource>
</web-resource>
</atlassian-plugin>
```